# Button color doesn't change in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, button

I have a button that has two states in which it has a different color, but the color does not change because the color of the button is automatically set by the theme. How can I avoid the color that the theme has set?

**Button code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/purple_200">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_note"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_states"
            android:text="@string/add_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**States code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/purple_200" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/purple_200"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/purple_500" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Theme code:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NotifyMe" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Keep your shapes in different files and then add them as drawables, And also try using state_selected instead of state_pressed.

Comment: Instead of Button use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use the Button from the androidx library **androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton** or you set the property of the button `backgroundTintMode` in the xml to the drawables.

Ideally you want to use the background property so its best you use this

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp" />
```